# CEF Sharp SSLKEYLOGFILE

Tags: chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I need to log the SSL KEY for decrypt SSL/TLS traffic with wireshark after the acquisition activities.

In chrome, chromium and Firefox is possible set a windows environment variable: SSLKEYLOGFILE.

This is an example the procedure: 
https://jimshaver.net/2015/02/11/decrypting-tls-browser-traffic-with-wireshark-the-easy-way/

In CEFSHARP don't work.

Is it possible to do this in cefsharp or is it a feature that will be added in the future?

Comment: There is no support currently, there is an open `PR`, https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/pull-requests/159/add-support-for-ssl-key-log-file/diff
The feature needs to be implemented in the `Chromium Embedded Framework`

Comment: I saw that the SSLKEYLOGFILE feature is still open. Can you tell me if there is a prediction for inclusion in the official build? Meanwhile it would be possible to try a version of cef with that SSLKEYLOGFILE feature included?

Comment: You will have to ask the `CEF` maintainer if there are any plans to merge the `PR`. You would have to build a version yourself that includes that relevant changes.

Comment: HI Amaitland, can you contact me with email at info@zinformatica.net 
for a job request on cefsharp?